# Interactive Popup/White Space

Tags: javascript, html

I am fairly new to the world of coding and am currently designing something using WAMP to assist the misses with her maths. In short I have a page with some basic maths questions on and I have JavaScript running on it to check whether the answers are correct or not.
What I would like to know is, can I use JavaScript or something similar to add in a link that if clicked will open a popup or something similar that the user can write a few bits down to help working out the sums?
I have seen a `<button onclick="window.open('whitespace.html');">Thinking Space</button>` but this doesnt allow the user to write anything down, obviously as its just a link to another page.

Comment: Short answer: yes you can. Either open a popup-window with a textarea in it, or just an overlaying container (e.g. a div) with an textarea in it. this is very basic javascript/html.

Comment: Thanks didnt even think about the textarea, was just looking at it as well. Basic I know but I did say I was fairly new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic sample, just pointing you in a possible direction:

```
<button onclick="window.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'block'">Thinking Space</button>

<div id="myDiv" style="display: none">
<textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="5">Test message</textarea>
<button onclick="window.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'none'">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use window.promt

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: good point, but this allows only one-liners. to write notes for math-questions this is rather small.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best answer but works for me. I created a link to a blank page that the user can then open. They can work the questions out, minimise it, forget about it and if they were to try to open a fresh one, close it or try to refresh it, they will get a message asking if they are sure they want to continue. Works exactly as Id hoped.

```
<textarea placeholder="Please be aware no data will be saved here. 
If closed or refreshed all data will be lost"</textarea>

<script>
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
  event.returnValue = "Reloading will cause any notes to be lost.";
});
</script>
```